# Update a field once the date/time set on a field =NOW

Tags: workflow, field-update

I have a trigger that will set a field_A__c's value by adding the date_A__c (when the case is set to 'In Progress') and minute_A__c (minutes to work on the case). Then field_A__c's will be a date/time in the future.

I want to update field_B__c once the field_A__c == NOW().

I tried using workflow for field update but it does not work. Workflow only works when I edit the record manually but if the system updates the record, workflow does not work.

Can you give me a workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: In your WF there is one option. Reevaluate WF rule when field update . Check the checkbox

Comment: Can a workflow work if the criteria is field_A__c = NOW() given that the field_A__c is in the future?

Comment: no you need to use time trigger and in criteria use this field.

Comment: But we cannot set field date/time value in time trigger right? The field_A__c value is unpredictable, it is based on computation

Comment: @TusharSharma is there a way to automate this?